# WASAPI - trouble with CoCreateInstance method

Tags: audio, wasapi

I am trying to capture audio from the mic using the windows core audio APIs

The relevant lines of code are

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);  
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;  
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,   (void**)&pEnumerator);
```

hr returns the following value-

> 0x800401f0 : CoInitialize has not been called.

I have adapted the sample program from the msdn page  - [Capturing an audio stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What could be wrong? Also I don't understand what the error means - from the descriptions I got from Google search and all.

I am using Visual studio 2012 express on Win7 Home Pro x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the error message clear enough? You need to call [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before calling CoCreateInstance (or using COM in any other way).